# Receiving 405 error on uploading file through VBA

Tags: php, vba, rest, codeigniter, outlook

I'm trying to upload a file from Outlook via VBA to my REST API.

I'm getting

> 405 not allowed

**VBA Code**

```vb
Sub uploadjustfile()
    Set objhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = "https://test-url.com/api/upload"
    objhttp.Open "POST", URL, False
    objhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
    objhttp.setOption 2, 13056
    objhttp.Send ("file=@D:/Zip/one.txt")
    MsgBox objhttp.responsetext
End Sub
```

**REST API Code**

```
$_FILES = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
$response = array('status'=>1);
$this->response($response,200);
```

This API code works within PHP script. With a test form, the output is as expected.

I am using CodeIgniter as back-end PHP framework.

Comment: How do you know if file_get_contents returns successfuly?

Comment: Thing is it runs successfully through PHP script and returns 405 error from VBA, if at all it would be hitting the URL successfully, it ideally should return status 1. So I think the issue is with VBA upload script only.